# How do i add current location in java code

Tags: java

How do I add current location into a Java code? What I mean by this is when I type "where am I", I want the output to be my current location? If anyone knows I would be very grateful if you could tell me. Thanks

Comment: That completely depends on your platform.

Comment: this question is too broad. you will need to use some other piece of code that already knows your location somehow.. a library that performs a lookup based on ip address, a driver that interacts w/ an actual GPS device, etc.

Comment: I am trying to build this on mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find location based on the ip address this link will help you.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using GeoLite. Pull the IP address from the [HTTP servlet request](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/), and check the location of the IP address using the GeoLite database.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/